# kubernetes can't tail log with the number of desired lines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I looking for the way to tail log with kubernetes

Why the test

```
kubectl log --tail=-30 mypod mycontainer | wc -l
190547
```

Not giving 30 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing it `-30`, which isn't a valid number of log lines, so it's returning all the lines. Pass it a positive number, i.e. `30`, and it should do what you want.